# Bootstrap fill remaining columns

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a bootstrap class that will fill however many columns have not already been taken?
for example i have this div tag that might be there and it might not if it isnt i want the second div to take up 12 columns, but if it is there only take up 8 columns. like this

```
<div class="row">
   <?php if(something){ ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div> </div>
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
   <div class="col-md-fill">
     <div> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

other than using

```
<div class="col-md-<?php
     if($count > 5){
         echo "8";
      } else {
         echo '12';
      }
       ?>">
```

Comment: Do you want to be dynamic? I mean `is col-sm-4` changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just finish your if statement with an else. One way, it uses a 4 and 8, the other it uses a 12 and takes up the whole row.

```
<div class="row">
   <?php if(something){ ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div> </div>
      </div>
   <?php } else { ?>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div> </div>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

*Sometimes I try something very stupid, but this time my stupidity surprises me...*

I've seen than if we append to a `div.row`  a `div` without any class, **this no-class div fills herself the empty space**....

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/bhgme789/1/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 bleu">bleu</div>
  <div class="rouge">rouge</div>  
</div>
    
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 bleu">bleu</div>
  <div class="rouge">rouge</div>  
</div>
    
      
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 bleu">bleu</div>
  <div class="rouge">rouge</div>  
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: @Sébastien It's working (I think) look at [this](http://www.bootply.com/S4u4LqHTCh)

Comment: Not stupid but Smart :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using Bootstrap v4 and v5 you should make use of the ['equal-width'](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#equal-width) column class `col`:

```
.col{
    flex: 1 0 0%;
}
```

I needed this for edge cases where the last column was pushed to the next line caused by rounding errors when the browser calculates the with in pixes using the percentage based column styles. So in some situations my last column with `col-2` was pushed down, using just `col` solved it.

A fiddle like the earlier given example with blue and red cells: http://jsfiddle.net/o14qh386/

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that, to keep code dry

```
<div class="row">
<div class="<?php if($something){echo 'col-md-push-4 col-md-8'}else{echo 'col-md-12'}">
</div>
</div>
```

I now noticed that you might want to put something `if is in 4`. in this case this might not be useful. If you just want to fulfil the space this is your solution