# How can I make a Bootstrap grid column fill the whole remaining row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I receive some elements, and I want to insert some elements in a page. These elements can be "small" or "big". I cannot know in advance how many elements I will receive, or their order.

- If they are "small", I want them to be large `col-4`.
- If they are "big", I want them to be large as much as possible, from the previous element to the end of the row.

So, a "big" element can be large `col-4`, `col-8` or `col-12` depending on its position.
In a picture:

[image]

The most-similar question I've found on SO is the following: [Bootstrap fill remaining columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874623/bootstrap-fill-remaining-columns)

I have tried to use the approach suggested in the question, but **it does not cover the case when, in the same row, you have a "small" element after a "big" element**. Using the same words from the linked question:

> it does not cover the case when, in the same row, you have a blue element after a rogue element

```css
.col-4{
  background:red;
}

.big{
 background:yellow; 
}

.row{
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1>
Expected result
</h1>
The goal is to obtain this same behaviour using the same style for every "big" element

<div class="container-fluid pt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4   mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>


    <div class="col-4 big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>

<h1>
Not working attemp 1 (don't use any col)
</h1>
Issue: The "big" elements start on a new row instead of filling the previous row.

<div class="container-fluid pt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4   mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<h1>
Not working attemp 2 (use only "col")
</h1>
Issue: Instead of occupying a whole row, the "big" elements shrink to make space for the next elements

<div class="container-fluid pt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4   mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>
    <div class="col big mb-1">
      big
    </div>
    <div class="col-4  mb-1">
      small
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhLq86o4/

So, how can I assign to the "big" elements the same class, so that the final results looks like the one described in the examples?

Comment: Why can't you use the code from your expected result? Are you saying you want to know what rules to apply to the `big` class so that you don't need to specify `col-4`, `col-8`, etc.? Why do you need to do this? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kmoser the elements are provided dynamically: I don't know in which order or quantity I will receive the "big" or "small" elements. Therefore, I want a single class for the "big" elements that can allow me to achieve the desired graphical output. While I am not sure anymore that I want to obtain such design, I still want to have an answer for didactical purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying multiple possible configurations (flex, grid, float, etc.), I figured out how you can do it as requested (**"big" elements have the same class**):

### CODE:

```css
.small {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

.big {
  background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Expected result
</h1>
The goal is to obtain this same behaviour using the same style for every "big" element

<div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>


  <div class="big">
    big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>
  <div class="big">
    big
  </div>
  <div class="small">
    small
  </div>
</div>
```

Some final words: since this is a *non-obvious task*, I recommend you to do it with native CSS, instead of struggling many days with BS classes.

Regards

Comment: Nice and clean solution, thanks! If we want to obtain a result aesthetically similar to the one in the example, we would need to insert `margin-bottom: 4px` and `padding-left: 12px`. Inserting the padding, sadly, ruins the final result (the big elements gets resized to 33%). Do you know why?

Comment: @FedericoDorato It breaks because this `float` layout is **not a real grid.** I don't suggest using this method in practice. It will also break in other ways. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75417121/13138364) for details and a recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't use `float`

@perplexyves' answer won't work in practice. It only *looks* correct because OP's example only has one word per `div`.

It breaks if we add some more content, e.g., to the second `div`:

[image]

It will also break in plenty of other ways (e.g., [padding/margins as OP noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322410/how-can-i-make-a-bootstrap-grid-column-fill-the-whole-remaining-row/75417121#comment133062979_75351759)) because the `float` layout is not a real grid, just a superficial hack.

---

### Use `flex` instead

For each "big" element:

1. Use Bootstrap's [`.flex-grow-1`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) class to fill the remaining row

   <sup>(Or if you prefer using your own `.big` class, add `.big { flex-grow: 1 !important; }` to your CSS)</sup>
2. Add an empty `div` to force a row break

```
<div class="col-4 flex-grow-1">big</div> <div></div>
<!--              ^fill to end           ^break into new row  -->
```

This `flex` layout will produce a real grid that works regardless of content/styling:

[image]

---

### Complete `flex` example

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">This is the second `div` using the `flex` layout. Note how the grid is completely fine now, even with longer/uneven content.</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-danger flex-grow-1">big</div> <div></div>
  <!--                        ^fill to end           ^break row -->
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-danger flex-grow-1">big</div> <div></div>
  <!--                        ^fill to end           ^break row -->
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-danger flex-grow-1">big</div> <div></div>
  <!--                        ^fill to end           ^break row -->
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
</div>
```

---

### Complete `flex` example with auto-inserted row breaks

If you are unable/unwilling to append the empty `div`s manually, use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert them automatically:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.flex-grow-1').forEach(big =>
  big.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div></div>'))
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">This is the second `div` using the `flex` layout and using JS to automatically insert the empty `div` row breaks.</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-danger flex-grow-1">big</div>
  <!--                        ^fill to end           ^row break will be auto-inserted here via JS -->
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-danger flex-grow-1">big</div>
  <!--                        ^fill to end           ^row break will be auto-inserted here via JS -->
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
  <div class="col-4 bg-danger flex-grow-1">big</div>
  <!--                        ^fill to end           ^row break will be auto-inserted here via JS -->
  <div class="col-4 bg-warning">small</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I regret that the bounty has been auto-awarded. This answer is powerful, thanks a lot! I hope you will be able to reach, and help, many people